# PubMed ID lookup _from_ bibtex entries?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

Getting bibtex entries from PubMed IDs (PMID/PMCID) is a solved problem; I need to go the *other* way and get the PMCIDs [PMIDs] for every article in my `.bib`, adding a `pmcid= [pmid=]` field to each article that has a match in pubmed. Is there a non-excruciating way to automate this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it) to format it as code.

Answer (score 2):

The NCBI's [Batch Citation Matcher](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/batchcitmatch) was the piece I was missing: its query strings can be generated from the .bib files and will pull PMIDs/PMCIDs from PubMed en masse.

Credit: http://ask.metafilter.com/238750/#3462327

Comment: For reference: [Batch Citation Matcher spec & examples](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK3827/#pubmedhelp.Batch_Citation_Matcher_Help)